# fopen не сохраняет содержимое в файл

Tags: php

Всем привет, у меня `Ubuntu`. На локальном сервере `Apache` есть файл с вот таким кодом:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.vk.com");
$fd = fopen("url.txt", "w");
fwrite($fd, $content);
fclose($fd);
```

Почему-то при этом коде не создаётся и не сохраняется результат в `url.txt`, даже в тот файл, который создан вручную.

Comment: Куда, по-вашему, указывает адрес "url.txt" во время исполнения скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, в этом коде нигде не проверяется, что "содержимое" хоть какое-то есть.
Во-вторых, нужно убедиться, что сообщения об ошибках доходят до пользователя. Поэтому:

1. Проверить, есть ли что-то в переменной `$content`.
2. добавить навсегда в начало скрипта код `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
3. *Временно* для отладки добавить также `ini_set('display_errors',1);`

При появлении ошибок не несем их радостно сюда в комменты, а гуглим самостоятельно.

Отвечая же на вопрос буквально, то команда "`fopen`" и не должна ничего записывать. Записывает команда  `fwrite()`. И если не было ошибок, то она прекрасно все записывает.